# No longer autoconnecting to home wifi

Tags: wireless

Every time I boot my computer it now manually requires me to connect to the wifi, and in the Advanced Network Configuration utility it creates a (mywifiname) with a number after it as if it was a different connection instead of using the saved settings for the wifi.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS